# How I can delete the particular contain from a csv file using linux

Tags: linux

112e37bf20b0319ae432cef13cea2465_6029147201001000000000; 1533737270079, value={..}
112e37bf20b0319ae432cef13cea2465_6029147201001000000001; 1533737270071, value={..}
112e37bf20b0319ae432cef13cea2465_6029147201001000000002; 1533737270072, value={..}

And I want like :

112e37bf20b0319ae432cef13cea2465_6029147201001000000000; value={..}
112e37bf20b0319ae432cef13cea2465_6029147201001000000001; value={..}
112e37bf20b0319ae432cef13cea2465_6029147201001000000002; value={..}

This is a part of a data of a big CSV file

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: This problem is solved :)

Comment: Then why not post your solution so others might gain the benefit?